# Does FaceID consume a significant amount of battery throughout the day?

Tags: battery, iphone

The FaceID requires the TrueDepth camera to recognise your face, plus there's also one sensor which emits infrared rays to map your face. So my question is will both these things consume significant amount of battery from my iPhone X and will it be better to turn the Require Attention for FaceID off so that the battery consumption is reduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - I tested this for several days with Face ID on and with Face ID off and I can't measure anything even close to 15 minutes or more difference in run times / overall battery difference.

My intuition is that whatever processing power is needed to power the infrared is more than counteracted by saving time unlocking where I'm tapping out my passcode to unlock the phone as opposed to having no passcode.

I disregarded entirely:

- not having a passcode / unlock
- disabling attention

My passphrase is something I type out with letters and numbers and not a numeric only short passcode, so [ymmv](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary) but I'd be surprised if you have measurable differences on your device and iOS 11.